# How to work with two aruguments in python class methods

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm trying to make a new method named feedback in my class. It should take an argument named grade along with self. When I run the program it shows the Exception: praise() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I've tried putting two arguments in the feedback method.

```
def praise(self):
    if self.name:
        return "You inspire me, {}".format(self.name)

def reassurance(self):
    if self.name:
        return "Chin up, {}. You'll get it next time!".format(self.name)
def feedback(self, grade):
    if self.name and grade > 50:
        return Student.praise()
    else:
        return Student.reassurance()
```

If the grade is above 50, it should return the result of the praise method. If it's 50 or below, it should return the reassurance method's result.

Comment: Is Student your class name? where is self.name being defined? Can you edit your question to include a complete example?

Comment: Yes, My class name is Student and name is also defined inside. Sorry I was unable to include that part in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call an instance method (one with `self` as the first, implicit, parameter), you have to actually call it *on* an instance. Here, `Student` is the type of class, not the instance. The instance is `self`, which gets passed implicitly.

Solution:

```
if self.name and grade > 50:
    return self.praise()
else:
    return self.reassurance()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Student.praise()` it is an *unbound* method, so `self` is not defined. That's the required positional argument you are missing.
You can either call it unbound and pass `self` (not preferred):

`Student.praise(self)`

Or (preferred), just call it as a bound method:

`self.praise()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full class, most similar to your code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade

    def praise(self):
        return f"You inspire me, {self.name}."

    def reassurance(self):
        return f"Chin up, {self.name}. You'll get it next time!"

    def feedback(self):
        if self.grade > 50:
            return Student.praise(self)
        else:
            return Student.reassurance(self)

Bob = Student('Bob', 60)
Jen = Student('Jen', 40)
print(Bob.feedback())
print(Jen.feedback())

> You inspire me, Bob.
> Chin up, Jen. You'll get it next time!
```

Or, as others have said, use self.praise() and self.reassurance() instead of Student.praise(self) or Student.reassurance(self).